# Discrete Fourier transform of $(1,1,1,1)$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, fast-fourier-transform

I am asked to determine the Fourier transform of $(1,1,1,1)$.

In the solution I found this:
[image: solution]

I don't get how is he transitioning from the $\omega$'s to $-i, i, -1, 1$ etc...

How to break it down, so that it's more understandable? Which middle-step (which could explain the path to solution better) is the professor not writing?

Any hints?

Comment: Do you understand the definition of $\omega$ given in the second line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we do a 4 sample DFT, we will be looking at powers of the complex 4th root of unity.

$w$ is the complex fourth root of unity $w^4 = 1$, we can pick $w = i$ or $w=-i$

It seems this aufgabe chooses the negative one. Now substitute $-i$ everywhere and you will get the matrix.

$$\cases{(-i)^0 = 1\\(-i)^1 = -i\\(-i)^2 = -1\\ (-i)^3=i}$$

And then it will be periodic, $w^5=w$ et.c.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Brings me a bit further. But how do we know w^4 = 1?

Comment: @ZelelB If the answer helps you, you can click uparrow. This encourages people to help you in the future. If you check the exercise it actually shows how $w$ is defined. You can use Euler formulas from there to find out.

Comment: Are you sure, we can pick w = i or w = -i ? Or is it because of the formula which says Fn^-1 (Inverse of Matrix Fn) = conjugate(Fn) ?

Comment: The transform will have all important properties the same, but it will be "time inverted". From an engineering perspective definitely not a bigger issue than keeping track of which normalization we have.

Comment: No I found why w = -i --> because e^(-2*pi*i/4) = e^((-pi/2)*i) = cos(-pi/2) + i*sin(-pi/2) = 0 + i*(-1) = -i    ---> I think choosing w = i would be wrong...

Comment: It would just be switching direction of time. Or if the sines go upwards or downwards first.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot!!